# Longest Increasing Path in a Matrix from leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search

[Solved](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-path-in-a-matrix/description/) this:

> Given an integer matrix, find the length of the longest increasing
>   path.
>
> From each cell, you can either move to four directions: left, right,
>   up or down. You may NOT move diagonally or move outside of the
>   boundary (i.e. wrap-around is not allowed).

Solution: do dfs traversal from every greater node to smaller node and store the result. Reuse the result when the same node is traversed again. Take the maximum of all the directions and return the result.

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestIncreasingPath(self, matrix):
        """
        :type matrix: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """
        def check_boundary(matrix, (row, col)):
            if row >= len(matrix) or row < 0:
                return False
            if col >= len(matrix[0]) or col < 0:
                return False
            return True

        def dfs(current, matrix, visited, memory):
            cost = 0
            if not check_boundary(matrix, current):
                return -1
            if current in visited:
                return memory[current]
            for direction in [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]]:
                new = current[0] + direction[0], current[1] + direction[1]
                visited.add(current)
                if check_boundary(matrix, new) and matrix[current[0]][current[1]] > matrix[new[0]][new[1]]:
                    cost = max(cost, 1 + dfs(new, matrix, visited, memory))
            memory[(current)] = cost
            return cost

        if not matrix:
            return 0
        maximum = 0
        visited, memory = set(), {}
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
                maximum = max(maximum, dfs((i, j), matrix, visited, memory))
        return maximum + 1
```

Comment: your code is broken `def check_boundary(matrix, (row, col)):` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, this is quite clean code. Your use of closures works quite well to hide implementation details.
The most obvious thing to change is to remove the class. In python things don't have to be in a class, and nothing is made better here by using one.

Here are some small other improvements
This version of check_boundary is smaller, and faster, and arguably cleaner.

```
def check_boundary(matrix, point):
    return 0 < point[0] < len(matrix) and 0 < point[1] < len(matrix[0])
```

dfs should use keyword arguments so you don't have to pass in initial conditions.

```
def dfs(current, matrix, visited=set(), memory={}):
```

This will simplify the end of your main method to

```
if not matrix:
    return 0
maximum = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        maximum = max(maximum, dfs((i, j), matrix))
return maximum + 1
```

This line `for direction in [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]]:` should have `Directions` factored out, and it should probably be a tuple of tuples instead of a list of lists, for a minor performance boost.
Other than that, this looks good.

Comment: What do you mean by not passing the initial conditions? Can you rewrite this code after your improvements?

Comment: does this make sense?

Comment: It is not compiling. Please check.

Comment: did this fix it?

Comment: https://ideone.com/kGNK2z nope

Comment: You have a typo. You have `def dfs(current=(0,0), matrix, visited=set(), memory={}):` but it should be `def dfs(current, matrix, visited=set(), memory={}):`

Comment: This won't work as we have to reuse visited and memory.

Comment: The way keyword arguments work is that if you supply them, the defaults are not used.